# poll() c function on windows

Tags: c, mingw

I want to know if I can use the poll() function on a MinGW development chain. I have CodeBlocks+MinGW. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried? Does it exist when you call it?  Does it work when you use it?  Why don't you just try it?  Do you have any evidence that it doesn't work?

Comment: Well, I heard it is POSIX only, I want to know if anybody has used it succesfully on MinGW, but I have not tried it.

Comment: Probably I ought to put it here as an answer, but this question is too old. So, you can't use; MinGW doesn't even knows, what is this the function. But here's funny thing that in the file winsock2.h of MinGW is defined a structure `pollfd`, have no even idea why. Probably it was a someone's hope, cruelly buried under thousandths of symbols of a source code. And, probably, I am one of those who hopers.

Answer (score 2):

> Last I heard, poll() was either not supported or provided limited functionality on mingw

That was in 2009.

In 2020... it is supported, but still "flawed", as illustrated with Git 2.25.2 (March 2020), where MinGW's `poll()` emulation has been improved.

See [commit 94f4d01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94f4d01932279c419844aa708bec31a26056bc6b) (17 Feb 2020) by [Alexandr Miloslavskiy (`SyntevoAlex`)](https://github.com/SyntevoAlex).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1ac37de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ac37deba2608490642432f16a82c95c0abf01fa), 09 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94f4d01932279c419844aa708bec31a26056bc6b): workaround for hangs when sending STDIN
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alexandr Miloslavskiy</sup>

> #### Explanation
>
> The problem here is flawed `poll()` implementation.
> When it tries to see if pipe can be written without blocking, it eventually calls `NtQueryInformationFile()` and tests `WriteQuotaAvailable`.
>
> **However, the meaning of quota was misunderstood**.
> The value of quota is reduced when either some data was written to a pipe, *or* there is a pending read on the pipe.
> Therefore, if there is a pending read of size >= than the pipe's buffer size, `poll()` will think that pipe is not writable and will hang forever, usually that means deadlocking both pipe users.
>
> I have studied the problem and found that Windows pipes track two values: `QuotaUsed` and `BytesInQueue`.
>
> The code in `poll()` apparently wants to know `BytesInQueue` instead of quota.
> Unfortunately, `BytesInQueue` can only be requested from read end of the pipe, while `poll()` receives write end.
>
> The git's implementation of `poll()` was copied from gnulib, which also contains a flawed implementation up to today.
>
> I also had a look at implementation in cygwin, which is also broken in a subtle way. It uses this code in `pipe_data_available()`:
>
> ```
> fpli.WriteQuotaAvailable = (fpli.OutboundQuota - fpli.ReadDataAvailable)
> ```
>
> However, `ReadDataAvailable` always returns 0 for the write end of the pipe, turning the code into an obfuscated version of returning pipe's total buffer size, which I guess will in turn have `poll()` always say that pipe is writable.
> The commit that introduced the code doesn't say anything about this change, so it could be some debugging code that slipped in.
>
> These are the typical sizes used in git:
>
> - 0x2000 - default read size in `strbuf_read()`
> - 0x1000 - default read size in CRT, used by `strbuf_getwholeline()`
> - 0x2000 - pipe buffer size in `compat\mingw.c`
>
> As a consequence, as soon as child process uses `strbuf_read()`, `poll()` in parent process will hang forever, deadlocking both processes.
>
> This results in two observable behaviors:
>
> 1. If parent process begins sending STDIN quickly (and usually that's the case), then first `poll()` will succeed and first block will go through.
>    `MAX_IO_SIZE_DEFAULT` is 8MB, so if STDIN exceeds 8MB, then it will deadlock.
> 2. If parent process waits a little bit for any reason (including OS scheduler) and child is first to issue `strbuf_read()`, then it will deadlock immediately even on small STDINs.
>
> The problem is illustrated by [`git stash push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), which will currently read the entire patch into memory and then send it to `git apply` via STDIN.
> If patch exceeds 8MB, git hangs on Windows.
>
> #### Possible solutions
>
> 1. **Somehow obtain `BytesInQueue` instead of `QuotaUsed`**
>    I did a pretty thorough search and didn't find any ways to obtain the value from write end of the pipe.
> 2. **Also give read end of the pipe to `poll()`**
>    That can be done, but it will probably invite some dirty code, because `poll()`
>
>    - can accept multiple pipes at once
>    - can accept things that are not pipes
>    - is expected to have a well known signature.
> 3. **Make `poll()` always reply "writable" for write end of the pipe**
>    Afterall it seems that cygwin (accidentally?) does that for years.
>    Also, it should be noted that `pump_io_round()` writes 8MB blocks, completely ignoring the fact that pipe's buffer size is only 8KB, which means that pipe gets clogged many times during that single write.
>    This may invite a deadlock, if child's STDERR/STDOUT gets clogged while it's trying to deal with 8MB of STDIN.
>    Such deadlocks could be defeated with writing less than pipe's buffer size per round, and always reading everything from STDOUT/STDERR before starting next round.
>    Therefore, making `poll()` always reply "writable" shouldn't cause any new issues or block any future solutions.
> 4. **Increase the size of the pipe's buffer**
>    The difference between `BytesInQueue` and `QuotaUsed` is the size of pending reads. Therefore, if buffer is bigger than size of reads, `poll()` won't hang so easily. However, I found that for example `strbuf_read()` will get more and more hungry as it reads large inputs, eventually surpassing any reasonable pipe buffer size.
>
> #### Chosen solution
>
> Make `poll()` always reply "writable" for write end of the pipe.
> Hopefully one day someone will find a way to implement it properly.
>
> #### Reproduction
>
> ```
> printf "%8388608s" X >large_file.txt 
> git stash push --include-untracked -- large_file.txt
> ```
>
> I have decided not to include this as test to avoid slowing down the test suite.
> I don't expect the specific problem to come back, and chances are that [`git stash push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)  will be reworked to avoid sending the entire patch via STDIN.

---

MinGW's poll() emulation also plays a role with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), fix deadlocks between main Git process and subprocess spawned via the `pipe_command()` API, that can kill "[`git add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a103ad6f3d58cf3d297a6b102876e2bbf09c98d7/Documentation/git-add.txt#L96)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--p))</sup> that was reimplemented in C recently.

See [commit 24b56ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24b56ae4aecc937a246efb94d283f54a7f59c7f1) (17 Aug 2022) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
See [commit 716c1f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/716c1f649e372a0784b9826cd3839e7b373e2ea9), [commit c6d3cce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6d3cce6f3c4d1a8d9ebc556c38f1335afdfeb6c), [commit 14eab81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14eab817e499cb047dd8ba21e688257a06d043f0), [commit ec4f39b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec4f39b2333db94096ec2d6b900eabaf4d1e3f1b), [commit 10f7433](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10f743389ca9a92720fb9c3d15f647888d82c297) (17 Aug 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a103ad6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a103ad6f3d58cf3d297a6b102876e2bbf09c98d7), 25 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`pipe_command()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14eab817e499cb047dd8ba21e688257a06d043f0): avoid xwrite() for writing to pipe
>
> <sup>Helped-by: René Scharfe</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> If `xwrite()` sees an `EAGAIN` response, it will loop forever until the write succeeds (or encounters a real error).
> This is due to [ef1cf01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef1cf0167a362cd504afdcc0eef4c3200ea6dfbb) ("`xwrite`: poll on non-blocking FDs", 2016-06-26, Git v2.10.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7725bebe21dfa4877dad74b1ac3d921f26f949cf) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08bb3500a2a718c3c78b0547c68601cafa7a8fd9)), with the idea that we won't be surprised by a descriptor unexpectedly set as non-blocking.
>
> But that will make things awkward when we do want a non-blocking descriptor, and a future patch will switch `pipe_command()` to using one.
> In that case, looping on `EAGAIN` is bad, because the process on the other end of the pipe may be waiting on us before doing another `read()` on the pipe, which would mean we deadlock.
>
> In practice we're not supposed to ever see `EAGAIN` here, since `poll()` will have just told us the descriptor is ready for writing.
> But our Windows emulation of `poll()` will always return "ready" for writing to a pipe descriptor! This is due to [94f4d01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94f4d01932279c419844aa708bec31a26056bc6b) ("`mingw`: workaround for hangs when sending STDIN", 2020-02-17, Git v2.26.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ac37deba2608490642432f16a82c95c0abf01fa)).
>
> Our best bet in that case is to keep handling other descriptors, as any `read()` we do may allow the child command to make forward progress (i.e., its `write()` finishes, and then it `read()`s from its stdin, freeing up space in the pipe buffer).
> This means we might busy-loop between `poll()` and `write()` on Windows if the child command is slow to read our input, but it's much better than the alternative of deadlocking.

---

With Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), [batch 14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/235986be822c9f8689be2e9a0b7804d0b1b6d821), the code that writes to pipes on **Windows** does not block anymore.

See [commit 19ed0df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19ed0dff8f3f19fc15e79d188d7bcaadf26f2f11) (30 Jan 2024) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1f9d274](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f9d2745fab473fda916642e535e7922cda421ca), 06 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`win32`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19ed0dff8f3f19fc15e79d188d7bcaadf26f2f11): special-case `ENOSPC` when writing to a pipe
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> Since [c6d3cce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6d3cce6f3c4d1a8d9ebc556c38f1335afdfeb6c) (`pipe_command()`: handle ENOSPC when writing to a pipe, 2022-08-17, Git v2.38.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a103ad6f3d58cf3d297a6b102876e2bbf09c98d7) listed in [batch #15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c46ea0ded70c921aedf22ced1afeea2a2a9ed26)) `(pipe_command()`: handle ENOSPC when writing to a pipe, 2022-08-17), one `write()` call that results in an `errno` value `ENOSPC` (which typically indicates out of disk space, which makes little sense in the context of a pipe) is treated the same as `EAGAIN`.
>
> However, contrary to expectations, as diagnosed in https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/101881#issuecomment-1428667015, when writing to a non-blocking pipe on Windows, an `errno` value of `ENOSPC` means something else: the write *fails*.
> Completely.
> Because more data was provided than the internal pipe buffer can handle.
> Somewhat surprising, considering that `write()` is allowed to write less than the specified amount, e.g. by writing only as much as fits in that buffer.
> But it does not, it writes no byte at all in that instance.
>
> Let's handle this by manually detecting when an `ENOSPC` indicates that a pipe's buffer is smaller than what needs to be written, and re-try using the pipe's buffer size as `size` parameter.
>
> It would be plausible to try writing the entire buffer in a loop, feeding pipe buffer-sized chunks, but experiments show that trying to write more than one buffer-sized chunk right after that will immediately fail because the buffer is unlikely to be drained as fast as `write()` could write again.
> And the whole point of a non-blocking pipe is to be non-blocking.
>
> Which means that the logic that determines the pipe's buffer size unfortunately has to be run potentially many times when writing large amounts of data to a non-blocking pipe, as there is no elegant way to cache that information between `write()` calls.
> It is the best we can do, though, so it has to be good enough.
>
> The diff is slightly chatty because it extends an already-existing conditional that special-cases a *different* `errno` value for pipes, and because this patch needs to account for the fact that `_get_osfhandle()` potentially overwrites `errno`.

Answer (score 1):

Last I heard, `poll()` was either not supported or provided limited functionality on mingw. But you can supply your own basic `poll()` that uses `select()` internally.

Comment: No! Win32 `select()` have almost nothing to do with the `poll()` function. It can not listen serial port, neither named pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Windows also provides a `WSAPoll()` function but the performance is worse than `select()`, from MSDN blog it was only implemented to improvement portability:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2006/10/26/wsapoll.aspx

Comment: `WSAPoll()` doesn't work for a named pipes, as I just found in your own answer. I am suspect that this neither works for a serial ports.

Comment: It is also worth noting that `WSAPoll()` doesn't report failed connections. Microsoft's advice to the author of cURL was to not use it and its API would be irrelevant in post Windows 8 - https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2012-10/0038.html